# Apache2 (reverse proxy) + Django + Gunicorn

Tags: apache-http-server, python, proxy, django

I have a problem with my Apache2 web server as reverse proxy server. The simplified server setup with my domain "example.com" looks like this:

[image: server setup]

If clients now go to the page `https://example.com/guacamole`, then the Apache2 web server should forward the requests to the Tomcat server (`https://127.0.0.1:8080/guacamole`). This part works.

If clients go to `https://example.com/mydjangoproject`, then the Apache2 web server should forward requests to the web server using Gunicorn and the Django project (`https://192.168.30.5:8000`). However, this configuration works only partially. The page `https://example.com/mydjangoproject` shows the main page of the Django project, but when calling the admin page `https://example.com/mydjangoproject/admin` the django application gives the error that the page `http://192.168.30.5:8000//admin` does not exist. It seems like the sub-URL "/mydjangoproject/" is removed when calling the admin page. What could that be?

This is my configuration:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem

    JKMount /* ajp13_worker

    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLProxyVerify none
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass /static/ !
    ProxyPass /mydjangoproject https://192.168.30.5:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse /mydjangoproject https://192.168.30.5:8000/
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Thanks for your help!

Edit:
When i try to enter the admin-page via `https://example.com/mydjangoproject/admin` then this error occurs:

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: First thing that I'd look at is the `proxypass` directives. Since `/mydjangoproject` is proxying `https://192.168.30.5:8000/`, then `https://example.com/mydjangoproject/admin` will return whatever it finds at `https://192.168.30.5:8000/admin`. Is the admin panel you're expecting being served from there?

Comment: Hi Kefka! Thanks for your reply. Normally there should be the admin-panel. I edited my post with the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll likely need to alter your `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` directives to get this to work.

You should try replacing these lines:

```
ProxyPass /static/ !
ProxyPass /mydjangoproject https://192.168.30.5:8000/
ProxyPassReverse /mydjangoproject https://192.168.30.5:8000/
```

With e.g.:

```
# "Convenience" URL
ProxyPass /mydjangoproject https://192.168.30.5:8000
ProxyPassReverse /mydjangoproject https://192.168.30.5:8000

# --- The lines below are what actually allow access to /admin ---

# Proxy /admin for login
ProxyPass /admin http://192.168.30.5:8000/admin
ProxyPassReverse /admin http://192.168.30.5:8000/admin

# Proxy /static for CSS, etc.
ProxyPass /static http://192.168.30.5:8000/static
ProxyPassReverse /static http://192.168.30.5:8000/static
```

You should then be able to use e.g. `https://example.com/admin` to access your Django `/admin` page and get the correct login dialog:

*ex. Django Admin Login*

[image: Django Admin Login - Screenshot]

> When I try to enter the admin page via `https://example.com/mydjangoproject/admin` an error occurs.

You should be able to add the following lines (in addition to those recommended above) to get this to (kind of) work:

```
ProxyPass /mydjangoproject/admin http://192.168.30.5:8000
ProxyPassReverse /mydjangoproject/admin http://192.168.30.5:8000
```

Note that Django seems to redirect ex. `https://example.com/mydjangoproject/admin` to ex. `https://example.com/admin` automatically, which breaks things unless you already have ex. `ProxyPass /admin http://192.168.30.5:8000/admin` as an existing entry (included above).

Comment: Thanks for your help! Now it works! Perfect :)

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you got it working. =)

Comment: @Anaksunaman, your solution is fine, I had the same problem, thanks! Now, there is an issue: I'm using netbox (which is an IPAM) that faces this same situation. Now, your workaround is somehow rigid if there are plenty of redirections to configure under apache with the several `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse`. Is there any solution that may do this for all the URLs?